# Heuristics checklist for tablets

Tags: heuristics

I am doing a heuristic evaluation of my company web based product designed for Tablets. Do you know any heuristics checklist specifically meant for tablets? If so can you please share it?

Comment: Could you say more about how you think some of the basic heuristic evaluation checklists (e.g. ones as answers in [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/while-establishing-heuristics-for-usability-testing-do-you-advise-using-your-own)) are not applicable to tablets?

Comment: One factor with mobile devices is:  can you read it in bright sunlight ?

Answer (score 3):

One that is always useful is Jakob Nielsens [Ten Usability Heuristics](http://www.useit.com/papers/heuristic/heuristic_list.html), which isn't specific to tablets, but can be used as a starting point for building your own checklist:

In short, these bullits apply:

> - Visibility of system status
> - Match between system and the real world
> - User control and freedom
> - Consistency and standards
> - Error prevention
> - Recognition rather than recall
> - Flexibility and efficiency of use
> - Aesthetic and minimalist design
> - Help users recognize, diagnose, and recover from errors
> - Help and documentation

Then add PhillipsWs' comment of **Readability in sunlight** and we only have a few more to add, such as **Ease of use when in motion** and **Cues to start again after pause**.

The last three all address the way a tablet is used, such as reading on the beach where the surrounding light is very bright and possibly the user is wearing sunglasses. Yes, it's hard do get it to work at all, but there is always ways to improve contrast between content and background. Tablet users also move around and stop and restart activities when it suits them. the last two suggestions address these situations.

To add further to the list, one could write a few use cases to see what needs to be measured in order to get the list more comprehensive.

Comment: @Shivanand You're welcome!